# Replace object in element using vue js or jquery

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

I have component in which i am looping through object array using v-for

```
<div v-for="item in goods" class="ui fluid card" :key="item.id" :id="item.id">
      <div v-for="badge in item.badges" :key="badge.id" class="ui labels">
        <a
          class="ui label"
          :style="{ backgroundColor: '#'+ badge.color, color: '#fff'}"
        >{{badge.label}}</a>
      </div>
       <button @click="replacement(item) "class="circular ui icon yellow button replacement">
          <div>
            <span style="font-size:25px">
              <strong v-if="item.related_goods!=null">{{item.related_goods.length}}</strong>
              <strong v-else>0</strong>
            </span>
            <span style="padding:1px">
              <small style="font-size:12px;">Replacement</small>
            </span>
          </div>
        </button>
        <button @click="complement(item) class="circular ui icon red button complementary">
          <div>
            <span style="font-size:25px">
              <strong v-if="item.alternative_goods!=null">{{item.alternative_goods.length}}</strong>
              <strong v-else>0</strong>
            </span>
            <span>
              <small style="font-size:12px">Complement</small>
            </span>
          </div>
        </button>
```

I am looping through goods to get single items in the same div i have 2 buttons replacement and complement after pressing i am getting the item object as it is.But i want to replace item object or pass new value to item. 
I have fetched complementary and replacement object in the method. How can i replace item object using vue or even using jquery as last resort.(i only posted short div here as item object have lots of fields)

Please let me know any solution i am new to vue.js. Let me know if you need any extra info

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you could simply update the `goods` array and the changes should be immediately reflected in the view.

Comment: Otherwise, what did you mean by "replacing items"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the splice method

```
vm.item.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

item is array 
indexOfItem is the starting index.
1 is the amount to be deleted.
newValue is a value to be inserted.

using the mutation method vue can detect changed into the array and update dom accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

in vue direct array assigment
e.g. a[i]=value does not get detected by vue.

Vue provide array mutation methods to change value in array which will promp refresh of dom

In your example use slice method

see [Doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods)